# How to marshal/unmarshal JSON in a Java application?

Tags: java, json

Assuming that I have the following JSON string:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "xyz"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "xyz"
  },
  "3": {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "xyz"
  },
  "4": {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "xyz"
  },
  "5": {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "xyz"
  },
  "6": {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "xyz"
  }
}
```

How would one go about creating this JSON structure from within a Java application?  Are there any good libraries to aid in marshaling and unmarshaling JSON for Java?

Answer (score 1):

With libraries like [jackson-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.8.6), you can easily transform json into an object representation and vice versa easily and efficiently with minimal code.

For example, the JSON you showed would be a `Map<String,SomeObject>` where `SomeObject` would be represented as follows:

```
public class SomeObject {
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

The map would be populated as follows, assuming a constructor that takes `id` and `name` for the map entry's value.

```
Map<String, SomeObject> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put( "1", new SomeObject( "12", "xyz" ) );
map.put( "2", new SomeObject( "12", "xyz" ) );
map.put( "3", new SomeObject( "12", "xyz" ) );
map.put( "4", new SomeObject( "12", "xyz" ) );
map.put( "5", new SomeObject( "12", "xyz" ) );
map.put( "6", new SomeObject( "12", "xyz" ) );
```

Now to get the JSON string from Java:

```
String output = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString( map );
```

If you had the JSON string and you wanted to get the object representation:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, SomeObject> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map = mapper.readValue( json, new TypeReference<Map<String,SomeObject>>(){} );
```

Obviously this is a basic overview.  It'd be wise to read the documentation for the Jackson API hosted on their github [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs).

Answer (score 1):

There are several popular libraries: jackson already mentioned here, gson, org.json and others.
There are also some convenience libraries that not dealing with serialization but can be useful for parsing, for example https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath. It possibly (didn't test it by myself) can be a bit slower but more convenient.
If you do not handle of tons of json documents per second or very large/comples documents (or both), you probably can select any library that looks simple for you. If you deal with cases that I mentioned, you'll need to read some performance test results in google or run your own, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would to recommend another library: [fastjson](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson). it's simple, faster and smaller, comparing Jackson.

```
Map<String, Object> map = JSON.parseObject(json, Map.class);
```